# Rotation of images in Slick2D

Tags: 2d, java, rotation, lwjgl, slick

I have have a rotation problem in the Slick2d library, the image is just not rotating (ie I set a rotation but no result is shown). Here is the rotation code:

```
if (input.IsKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT))  {
    velocity.x = -1;

    rotation = (float)Math.toRadians(180);
}
```

That is meant to set the rotation of image to 180 degress.

Then I render the image with an origin of the center of the image:

```
image.setCenterOfRotation(image.getWidth() * scale / 2, image.getHeight() * scale * / 2);
image.setRotation(rotation);

image.draw(position.x, position.y, scale);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to rotate the image over time or just set the rotation once when you're moving left?  Because at best you're doing the latter right now.

Comment: Rotate the image when you move left, so when you hit the left button the image is meant to rotate 180 degress instantly. Which isn't working.

Comment: As far as I know, `Image.setRotation(float)` accepts degrees, not radians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I know, Image.setRotation(float) accepts degrees, not radians. Bobby.

Thanks Bobby!

Comment: Oh dear...I just confused Radians with Grads, otherwise I'd have posted that as answer anyway. :/